# mpchart memory improvement (OOM)

Tags: android, performance, memory

How can i fix memory leak in mpChart when it's a list?
My phone crash when the list reached 100 item of chart.
Any solution for decrease the memory when draw line chart in list? 
Thank you

Comment: recall `onDestroyView()` for release memory.

Comment: sorry but this is the charts list when i load more, cant be switch screen